# Vue of Typescript. Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/mycomponent.vue'

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue of typescript as well as typescript in Express. Everything worked until i want to use single file component in vue.js.
Here is my component,

```html
<template>
  <div>This is a simple component. {{msg}}</div> 
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "you"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My webpack file,

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPugPlugin = require('html-webpack-pug-plugin');
const Webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: [
            './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
            './dist/web/views/common/client/ts/_main.js',
            './web/views/common/client/style/main.scss'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        ts: 'ts-loader'
                    },
                    esModule: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: false
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }]
                })
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                loader: 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './web/views/common/_layout.pug',
            filename: '../web/views/common/layout.pug',
            filetype: 'pug'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPugPlugin(),
        new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            Popper: 'popper.js'
        })
    ]
};
```

If I don't use single file component, everything works, but when i introduce .vue file, it will show this error,

**ERROR in ./dist/web/views/about/client/ts/_aboutController.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/mycomponent.vue' in '/Users/george/github/bochure/dist/web/views/about/client/ts'
 @ ./dist/web/views/about/client/ts/_aboutController.js 4:24-63
 @ ./dist/web/views/common/client/ts/_main.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js ./dist/web/views/common/client/ts/_main.js ./web/views/common/client/style/main.scss**

Can anyone help me? You can also download my source at github and help me out. Many thanks.

**git@github.com:geforcesong/bochure.git**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

`'./components/mycomponent.vue'`

`'../components/mycomponent.vue'`

This might work in some cases.

Comment: I was using `'@components/mycomponent.vue'`. replacing it with `../` got my issue solved

Feb, 2022

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to check the **component path** first.
If you are embedding one vue component into another then check if both are on the **same directory level**.

If they are then you can use './component-name.vue' and you will be good to go.